# Passing a config file to Google Cloud Function using GitHub Actions and GitHub Secrets

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I have a `config.py` file on my development machine that stores multiple dictionaries for my config settings.

`config.py`:

```
SERVICE_ONE_CREDENTIALS = {
    "CLIENT_ID": 000,
    "CLIENT_SECRET": "abc123"
}

SERVICE_TWO_CREDENTIALS = {
    "VERIFY_TOKEN": "abc123"
}
...
```

I recently setup this [GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cloud-functions-deploy) to automatically deploy the changes that are pushed to the repository into a Google Cloud Function, and ran into a problem when trying to copy this configuration file over since the file is being ignore from git due to it storing sensitive credentials.

I've been trying to find a way to copy this file over to the Cloud Function but haven't been successful. I would prefer to stay away from using environment variables due to the number of keys there are. I did look into using key management services, but I first wanted to see if it would be possible to store the file in GitHub Secrets and pass it along to the function.

As a backup, I did consider encrypting the config file, adding it to the git repo, and storing the decryption key in GitHub secrets. With that, I could decrypt the file in the Cloud Function before starting the app workflow. This doesn't seem like a great idea though, but would be interested to see if anyone has done this or what your thoughts are on this.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you encrypt and put in a repo at least it's not clear text and someone can't get to the secret without a private key (which of course you don't check in).  I do something similar in my dotfiles repo where I check in dat files with my secrets and the private key isn't checked in.  That would have to be a secret in actions and written to disk to be used.  It's a bit of machinery but possible.

Using github secrets is a secure path because you don't check-in anything, it's securely stored and we pass it JIT if it's referenced. dislosure, I work on actions.

One consideration with that is we redact secrets on the fly from the logs but it's done one line at a time.  multiline secrets are not good.

So a couple of options ...

You can manage the actual secret (abc123) as a secret and echo the config file to a file with the secret.  As you noted you have to manage each secret separately.  IMHO, it's not a big deal since abc123 is actually the secret.  I would probably lean into that path.

Another option is to base64 encode the config file, store that as a secret in github actions and echo base64 decoded to a file.  Don't worry, base64 isn't a security mechanism here.  It's a transport to get it to a single line and if it accidentally leaks into the logs (the command line you run) the base64 version of it (which could easily be decoded) will be redacted from the logs.

There's likely other options but hope that helped.

Comment: I did end up going with the encryption route but I ran into a problem with this because my config file is shared between multiple repositories (DataAccessLayer, Utils, etc.). Since some secrets are shared across repositories I would prefer to just have one config file to update.

So if for example I put the config file in the Utils package and I import the Utils package in my logic package that gets deploying using github actions, the file will not be decrypted since it's a dependency and not in the root directory.

Any recommendation for this workflow?